# Notice: Undefined offset: 1 when returning number that is below thousand

Tags: php, number-formatting

I got this code online and implemented it in a function that retrieves data from feed URLs. here's the code:

```
function subs_count() {
  $x = esc_attr( subs_count_ret() );
  $x_number_format = number_format($x);
  $x_array = explode(',', $x_number_format);
  $x_parts = array('k', 'm', 'b', 't');
  $x_count_parts = count($x_array) - 1;
  $x_display = $x_array[0] . ((int) $x_array[1][0] !== 0 ? '.' . $x_array[1][0] : '');
  $x_display .= $x_parts[$x_count_parts - 1];
  return $x_display;
}
```

The code works fine if the number is above `1k`, but when the retrieved number is `< 1k` it returns that number in addition to below-error:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\preview\wp-content\plugins\xx\xx.php on line 7
```

and

`Notice: Undefined offset: -1 in C:\wamp\www\preview\wp-content\plugins\xx\xx.php on line 8`

Any ideas ?

Thank you!

Comment: So basically you decided to not tell us what line the error was on ?

Comment: @adeneo Well then it seems like Easter Egg hunt?

Comment: Or at least if `PATH` was relevant to that code.

Comment: Sorry there you go `Notice: Undefined variable: x in C:\wamp\www\preview\wp-content\plugins\xx\xx.php on line 213`. WAMP server

Comment: which one is line 213 ?

Comment: Yep I forgot, how would you tell ? it's line 7. Apologize again !

Comment: Yes the function works fine, it returns data, the issue is in this line
 ` $x_display = $x_array[0] . ((int) $x_array[1][0] !== 0 ? '.' . $x_array[1][0] : '');` and it's line 7

Comment: The `esc_attr` call? If so we would need to know what `subs_count_ret()` returns ?

Comment: Okay, let's say it returns 209 ( `subs_count_ret()` ) @adeneo

Comment: `undefined !== 209`  I'm confused what error is which.  Undefined is pretty clear.  The other, first one... well maybe try `isset($x_array[1])`...

Comment: Thanks. I tested `$x = 1111;` and it returned `1.1k`, so far so good. But, when I tried `$x = 111;` it returned the error above + 111 below error message.. I am a bit of PHP newb, I don't see `array('k', 'm', 'b', 't');` support for the numbers below 1k in that array.. @ficuscr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. I placed the entire code inside `subs_count_ret()` function, and it worked fine, plus, I needed this condition:

```
if(empty($num) || $num < 1000) return $num;
```

full code:

```
function subs_count_ret() {
    $xmlData = file_get_contents( 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/user' ); 
    $xmlData = str_replace('yt:', 'yt', $xmlData); 
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlData); 
    $ytio_subs = $xml->ytstatistics['subscriberCount'];
    $num = $ytio_subs;
        if(empty($num) || $num < 1000) return $num;
        $x = round($num);
        $x_number_format = number_format($x);
        $x_array = explode(',', $x_number_format);
        $x_parts = array('k', 'm', 'b', 't');
        $x_count_parts = count($x_array) - 1;
        $x_display = $x;
        $x_display = $x_array[0] . ((int) $x_array[1][0] !== 0 ? '.' . $x_array[1][0] : '');
        $x_display .= $x_parts[$x_count_parts - 1];
        return  $x_display;
}
```

Thank you everyone! Have a nice day !